# SELECT MySQL field that contains a substring

Tags: mysql, sql, string

Using LIKE is very common in MySQL. We use it like this: `WHERE field LIKE '%substring%'`. Where we have a substring and field has full string. But what I need is something opposite. I have substrings in field. So, I want that row which contains a substring of my string. Suppose the table is:

```
----+-------------------
 id | keyword
----+-------------------
  1 | admission
----+-------------------
  2 | head of the dept
----+-------------------
```

and I have a string from user: `Tell me about admission info`. I need such a MySQL query that returns `admission` as this is a substring of user string. Something like:

```
SELECT keyword FROM table WHERE (keyword is a substring of 'Tell me about admission info')
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You re looking for the [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator

> Pattern matching using SQL simple regular expression comparison.
>   Returns 1 (TRUE) or 0 (FALSE). If either expr or pat is NULL, the
>   result is NULL.

Something like

```
SELECT  keyword 
FROM    table 
WHERE   ('Tell me about admission info' LIKE CONCAT('%', keyword, '%'))
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6873/1)

Answer (score 2):

This work fine, using `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT  keyword 
FROM    table 
WHERE   'Tell me about admission info' REGEXP keyword;
```

But this work only if `keyword` don't contain *Regular expression*'s escapes...

I.e. This will work fine while `keyword` contain only letters, numbers, spaces and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'Tell me about admission info' 
   LIKE CONCAT('%',`keyword`,'%')
   THEN `keyword` else null END as `keyword`

FROM    table1

WHERE CASE WHEN 'Tell me about admission info' 
  LIKE CONCAT('%',`keyword`,'%')
  THEN `keyword` else null END is not null;
```

**[SQL Fiddle..](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6873/19/0)**