# Check if row contains a substring from a string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string

I want to check if the table `ssd` has a row containing the value `2280` (a substring) and it does but the problem is I can only get a string to check which contains multiple values including the substring. The table `ssd`:

```
----+-------------------
 id | m2len
----+-------------------
  1 | 2280
----+-------------------
  2 | 2260 
----+------------------
```

The query:

```
$m2len = "2242 2260 2280 22110"
$sql = "SELECT m2len FROM ssd WHER m2len LIKE '%$m2len%'";
```

This query gives no output even if the table `ssd` has the row `m2len` containing the value `2280`.

Is there a way to check whether a row contains a substring (`2280`) from a string (`2242 2260 2280 22110`) with MySQL?

**Note:** This question may look similar to [SELECT MySQL field that contains a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18809976/select-mysql-field-that-contains-a-substring) but it's not as the other question simply checks if a string contains a substring but here I am trying to do the opposite.

**Update:**

@JohnWoo's Answer Worked. But there's a problem for other values like `0`, `80`, `22` it returns those rows as well which is not required. **I want an exact match.**

The table may also contain values like:

```
id | m2len
----+-------------------
  1 | 2280
----+-------------------
  2 | 2260 
----+------------------
  3 | 0
----+------------------
  4 | 80 
----+------------------
```

Comment: What is the exact problem, do you need to extract only the third value from your string, do you want to match on all values, etc.?

Comment: The row contains only one value i.e `2280` but the string I have to check has multiple values `2242 2260 2280 22110`. Now I cannot use `LIKE %'2242 2260 2280 22110'%` to look for `2280`

Comment: Seems like you want to check against each element in the string. You could break the variable `$m2len` into an array() using _explode_ `$m2len_array = explode(" ",$m2len);` Use a foreach on the `$m2len_array` to build the where part of your query against each array element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform this:

```
"2242 2260 2280 22110"
```

Into this:

```
"2242, 2260, 2280, 22110"
```

And build your query. The following is an over simplified version:

```
$m2len = "2242 2260 2280 22110";
$csv = str_replace(" ", ", ", $m2len);
$sql = "SELECT m2len FROM ssd WHER m2len IN ($csv)";
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to interchange the value and the column in your query,

```
$m2len = "2242 2260 2280 22110"
$sql = "SELECT m2len FROM ssd WHERE '$m2len' LIKE CONCAT('%', m2len, '%')";
```

Here's a [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02ab61/1)

There is another solution which uses [FIND_IN_SET()] but the values must be separated by a comma.

```
$m2len = "2242 2260 2280 22110";
$m2len = str_replace(" ",",",$m2len);
$sql = "SELECT m2len FROM ssd WHERE FIND_IN_SET(m2len,'$m2len')";
```

Here's a [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e84826/1).

Comment: you can also use `FIND_IN_SET`

Answer (score 0):

As you are in php, you can use it, you should take care of sql injection, but here is not the question :

```
$m2len = "2242 2260 2280 22110";
$prepareM2len = "(".substring(" ",",",$m2len).")";
$sql = "SELECT m2len FROM ssd WHER m2len in ".$prepareM2len ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT m2len FROM ssd WHERE m2len = MID('$m2len',11,4)";
```

I assumed `2280` always in the same position